# Usecases/experience of JavaScript for HPC (High Performance Computing)

Tags: javascript, hadoop, hpc

Microsoft has [announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/12/12/improved-developer-experience-interoperability-and-scalability-on-windows-azure.aspx) preview version of Hadoop on Azure. JavaScript can also be used to write MapReduce jobs on Hadoop.

I know that there had been a lot of work on JavaScript in the browsers for the last few years to improve the performance (especially [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)). Can anyone share use-cases or their experience using JavaScript for HPC (High Performance Computing)?

Here is an intersting article on using JavaScript on Hadoop with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

Comment: umm, there are plenty of Node.js success stories, like this [article](http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/) , but im not sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/ says that it is for Network application. While Hadoop is for distributed computing.

Comment: I think microsoft added this just for convenience, mainly because the new windows 8 metro does include javascript and they have a new native renderer within the next visual studio. However, I think this is just a simple streaming job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Rhino to be honest, but I do know some stuff about Node.js (which is based on [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)), and one of the most important is that [it's not recommended for heavy cpu usage apps](http://nodeguide.com/convincing_the_boss.html#cpu-heavy-apps).

The best thing would be to write C++ addons for stuff that you know will take an important amount of CPU.

Another useful link that you should read is about [Fabric](http://fabric-engine.com/products/what-is-fabric-engine/) and (for ex.) what it does to improve a basic fibonacci server to perform better: http://fabric-engine.com/2011/11/benchmark-node-js-fibonacci-server/

Comment: The OP was `case-studies/experience on JS for HPC` and not much related to Rhino. I just referenced a way of using JS with Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Utility nodes. Expose an API for storing data, and an API for computations on that stored data.

MPI sucks for reuse. HTTP is the new unix pipe.

A good starter project would be a molecular dynamics API. Input a JSON, get back the state of the system every time you query the node until you ask it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

to do HPC (High-Performance Computing) effectively you need to implement threads to get better performance. javascript is a single-threaded language it has one call stack and one memory heap. you should not do HPC with js.